# How to persist a List<Object>

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jaxb

I've got a construct like this and need to persist the List of Objects. This is constructed because the `ExtensionContainer` can hold some objects from custom namespaces.

```
@Entity
@Data
public static class ExtensionContainer implements Serializable {
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    @OneToMany
    private List<Object> any;
}
```

How can I persist it? The Objects in the List can be persisted (`@Entity`).

Comment: You can't. Your list can hold anything and not everything can be serialized.

Comment: The elements in the list implement Serializable. Is there a workaround?

Comment: No they don't. Maybe in practical terms, but not to the satisfaction of the compiler. If you want a list of Serializable objects, why isn't it declared as `List<Serializable>`? (doubt this will make any difference, but it's certainly more correct. A `List<Serializable>` is at least *possible* to serialize, unlike a `List<Object>`)

Comment: Hibernate won't be able to determine the types of the entities and would especially have difficulties reading them. So what you could try is make the entire list a blob or serialize to something like json (if possible for your objects, might require a custom usertype, e.g. like [this](https://fabriziofortino.github.io/articles/hibernate-json-usertype/#:~:text=Hibernate%20JSON%20UserType%3A%20simple%20handling%20of%20JSON%20objects%20with%20Jackson,-By%20Fabrizio%20Fortino&text=Hibernate%20provides%20a%20wide%20range,column%20to%20a%20specific%20type.)).